# RocketRAID 640 - Ubuntu 16.04 / Kernel 4.13 Support

Tags: raid

Anyone have any idea how to get a RocketRAID 640 working under 16.04? Seems anything official or even suggested is for much older Kernels or Ubuntu releases.

This has been a reliable and solid controller under all releases of Windows since 7 but it looks like the Linux side of things has been neglected.

I've tried to make a couple of the older releases, but of course they fail as soon as they detect any recent kernel.

Any suggestions, besides buying a new controller? Currently, this controller runs 4 6TB RED drives on my Windows 10 box (and has done so 24/7 for about two years now with no rebuilding or failure), but it's a no-go under Ubuntu.

Comment: It's a fakeraid card.  Don't bother setting it up. Use Linux kernels md support. Read [this](https://skrypuch.com/raid/) about fakeraid and why not to go there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dig, but there are some updated versions of the driver source. I was running rr64xl-linux-src-v1.3.11 that ran with Ubuntu 16.04. To add Kernel 4.13 support I had to patch several files. Here are some links that might help:

- [Seems to be some unofficial patched driver source](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/BIOS_Driver/RR64xL/Linux/)
- [Discussion where I learned about applying the required patch to my 1.3.11 source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1899544&page=10). Perhaps the above driver source already includes these?

I don't use the RAID capabilities of this card. I simply wanted to add 4 SATA large capacity drives. I have 8TB and 4TB drives for my movies. The drives do occasionally go off line, but not to the point that I need to throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

I patched the rr64x driver and it now works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1 (jbod mode).
See https://bitbucket.org/yurac/rr64x.
Hope this helps